# sort the contents of the list with jquery

Tags: jquery, sorting

I need to sort alphabetically the list items. A list item contains html which cannot be changed. So I need only to sort the "visible" part.

This is the script I have:

```
 $('.box').each(function(){
var labels = []
var sortedlis = [];

var lis = $(this).find('li');

$(this).find('li').each(function(){
     labels.push( $(this).find('label').text() );
 });


labels.sort();

console.log(labels);

for (i=0; i< lis.length; i++){
    console.log('start loop 1');

    for (ind = 0; ind< labels.length; ind++){
        console.log('start loop 2');

        if (lis[i].textContent == labels[ind]){
                  sortedlis[ind] = lis[i];
                 // console.log(ind + ' sorted lis ind');
                 console.log(i +' true ' + lis[i].textContent + ' ind= '+ind);

         }else{
             console.log(i + ' false');
         }
    }
}

console.log(sortedlis);

for(index = 0; index < sortedlis.length; index++){

    //lis[index].css('background', 'red');
    lis[index].innerHTML = sortedlis[index].innerHTML;

}


});
```

I have made a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tf0hgsvf/4/). I cannot sort out why the script doesn't work... Could anyone point me to the mistake in code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a simple `sort` to achieve the alphabetical sort of your list:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var mylist = $('#myUL');
  var listitems = mylist.children('li').get();
  listitems.sort(function(a, b) {
    return $(a).text().toUpperCase().localeCompare($(b).text().toUpperCase());
  })
  $.each(listitems, function(idx, itm) {
    mylist.append(itm);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box-content box">
  <ul id="myUL">
    <li><label class="sf-checked"><input data-keyword="lampmodel-bouwlamp" type="checkbox" name="attribute[357]" value="Bouwlamp" checked="checked">Bouwlamp </label></li>
    <li><label><input data-keyword="lampmodel-bouwlamp-werklamp" type="checkbox" name="attribute[357]" value="Werklamp">Werklamp</label></li>
    <li><label><input data-keyword="lampmodel-breedstraler-bouwlamp-werklamp" type="checkbox" name="attribute[357]" value="Breedstraler">Breedstraler</label></li>
    <li><label><input data-keyword="lampmodel-looplamp-werklamp" type="checkbox" name="attribute[357]" value="Looplamp">Looplamp</label></li>
    <li><label><input data-keyword="lampmodel-tl-lamp" type="checkbox" name="attribute[357]" value="TL-lamp">TL-lamp </label></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your last `for` loop, you are updating `<li>` with the innerHtml property. But js variable `sortedlis` uses reference and when the last property is set, you already have set it before.

That's why you duplicate your `Breedstraler` label.

Your algorithm is not bad but it's too complicate to understand. You have to improve, Milan answer is a better way ;)

Comment: Not looking for an easy way :-D Thanks for the explanation!